# define variable for directory in htaccess and use it

Tags: .htaccess, variables, directory

Lets think that I have such code in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/registration/?$ admin/qeyd.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/login/?$ admin/login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/profile/?$ admin/profile.php [NC,L]
```

But I want to define a variable for "admin" and write it like this:
    admin_directory_variable = custom_name

```
RewriteRule ^custom_name/registration/?$ admin/qeyd.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^custom_name/login/?$ admin/login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^custom_name/profile/?$ admin/profile.php [NC,L]
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: Variables can be used in many ways. What is the use case here of using a variable? Do you just want to avoid using `admin` path multiple times?

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid using admin path multiple times

Comment: You can actually avoid typing `admin/` by placing all 3 rules in `admin/` directory.

Comment: Which rules ? Can you write please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `admin/.htaccess` file and use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteRule ^registration/?$ qeyd.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(login|profile)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

Apache 2.4 has the *Define* keyword which you use like this:

```
Define name value
```

and use like this:

```
DocumentRoot ${name}
```

Unfortunately, it can't be used in .htaccess files.  See [Apache 2.4 documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#define)